# How to access build/intermediates on CircleCI 2.0?

Tags: android, sonarqube, circleci, circleci-2.0, sonarcloud

Trying to run Sonar on a Circle CI 2.0 Android project.

For whatever reason when I try to set various configs to the build/intermediates director it can't find it.

Do I have to run some build first?

Is it in a different directory on Circle?

Comment: You need to add more information about your setup. Any configuration file should be in the project root.

Comment: This would need a [mcve] to be answerable. Would you edit your question? How can readers replicate what you are (not) getting?